# KnockoutJS - how to insert values into html viewmodel?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have this as my knockout view model:

`<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="CreateChatWindow('SomeValue');" class="socialsChat">`

Now, how can I insert my model value in place of `SomeValue`?

Comment: What you're showing is your HTML, not your view model.  Can you show us your view model (your javascript view model) as well as how you initialize your view model and apply the bindings?

Comment: You seem to be missing some fundamental knowledge, have you gone through the [knockout tutorials](http://learn.knockoutjs.com)

Comment: possible duplicate of [KnockoutJS - attr binding $data not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15853844/knockoutjs-attr-binding-data-not-working)

Comment: and you are using knockout for what exactly?

Answer (score 2):

You must handle click event with knockoutjs, try something like this:

```
<a href="#" data-bind="click: CreateChatWindow($root.someValue)">I'm a link</a>
```

Where $root is a reference to your viewModel.