# KnockoutJS - attr binding $data not working

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have this:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" data-bind="attr: { onclick: 'CreateChatWindow(\'$data.peer\');'}" class="socialsChat"><img src="~/Content/Styles/Default/Images/Icons/chat.png"/></a>
```

Now, the output looks like that:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="socialsChat" onclick="CreateChatWindow('$data.peer');"><img src="~/Content/Styles/Default/Images/Icons/chat.png"/></a>
```

Why isn't `$data.peer` getting it's value from my model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, why 'onclick'? this should be 'click', at least I'm using this at newest version. Second, why you use \'? and third, passing arguments to viewmodel methos looks like this

```
data-bind="click: function() { CreateChatWindow($data); }"
```

Comment: Yes ure right, I had syntax error. And click is not working for me, but since I fixed my code everything works fine now. Thanks. :)